# How to catch event when touched outside the Dialog?

Tags: android

I have a dialog for my application. I want to catch event when the user clicks outside the dialog. What do I have to do for this?

Thank all!

Answer (score 1):

`Dialog` has the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)` method. If you pass true as parameter the dialog will be dismiss when you touch outside the bounds of its window